How to check if a text file contains domain names using batch script
I am currently struggling to check if a text file contains domain names, if it does I would the IP addresses of the domain names to be displayed and if it does not, I would like an error message of "No domain names found in this file" to be displayed.
I tried to test my code by seeing if it displays the correct error message if a file with no domain names entered, but it does not.
Here is my code:
for /f "tokens=*" %%G in (%FILENAME%) do (
     nslookup %%G >nul &1
     if "!errorlevel!"=="0" (
          echo Domain Name: %%G
          set ip=
          for /f "tokens=1*" %%H in ('nslookup  %%G 2^>nul ^|more +3 ^| findstr /R /C:"[1-9][0-9]*\.[1-9][0-9]*\.[1-9][0-9]*\.[1-9][0-9]*"') do (
               if !ip! equ 1 (
                    echo IP Address: %%H
                    set ip=
               ) else (
                    echo %%H
               )
          )
          echo ---------------------------
     )
) 
    
if not "%errorlevel%"=="0" (
     echo No domain names found in this file
     exit /b
)

:end
exit /b


Why did you delete your previous question on this same code? All you had to do was fix 2 errors in one line of code with your last set of code.

if not "%errorlevel%"=="0" ( is within a code block and therefore needs delayed expansion (or simply use if errorlevel 1 (, see if /? for details)

The variable ip never gets assigned a value.

And if you are trying to output all the IP Addresses from NSLOOKUP you should follow @Stephan exact code here
